# How to install clang?

Tags: software-installation, compiling, scientific-linux

I have downloaded the "Clang for x86_64 OpenSUSE 13.1" (I am on Scientific Linux) pre-built binary from here:

http://llvm.org/releases/download.html

(Should I have got the Fedora one??)

and I untarred in the Downloads folder- I have a clang folder with bin, docs, include, lib and share folders.

I did find this page:

https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/INSTALL.txt

advising what to do next, but their steps do not see to synch with the folders I have?

What do I need to do next to install clang compiler?

Also, how does my environment know where the clang compiler will be located?

Comment: I'd go with the Fedora one. Scientific LInux is a clone of RHEL. RHEL and Fedora are close. Try rebuilding the rpm on your system. If you don't know how to do that, ask.

Comment: Hi, would you be able to give explicit instructions? What is the rpm? Is it one of the links on the link I provided? What do I need to do to build it? Where should I build it?

Comment: I don't actually use rpms. You'll need to locate the spec file they are using. Let me see if I can find it. If you want to hop into the unix.sx chat room it would be easier - http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux

Comment: If you do a clone of the source repos, the rpm spec file is at the top level. You'll then need to set things up to build correctly. I'd suggest asking directly in an llvm/clang forum. If you get no joy there, you can try asking here, but since the project certainly builds their own rpms, they know how to do so. You could also suggest to them that they make their source rpms publicly available. That would save people who want to rebuild a lot of work.